# how to use a separate STA thread to call clipboard from timer in console application?

Tags: multithreading, timer, console, clipboard, single-threaded

I am struggling with using Clipboard from a console application. The error handler would return the following error.

"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made"

I set the STA attribute to the main function and that worked well when calling from main. However, I need to cyclically call that function and in this case I get back that error.

I'm trying to figure out how to use an own thread in my funtion. Now, it just works once but in the 2nd call from my timer, I am not able to reach the area of the code after where I created the thread

```
public string getRawData()
{
  string sChatRawTxt = string.Empty;

  try
  {
    // copy data to clipboard using an Autoit script

    Process.Start("copyChatToClipboard.au3");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    Thread staThread = new Thread(x =>
    {
      if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
      {
        sChatRawTxt = Clipboard.GetText();
        Clipboard.Clear();
      }
    });
    staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    staThread.Start();
    staThread.Join();

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }

  return sChatRawTxt;
}
```

This is the timer from where my function is called. If I set a breakpoint to separateComments, it only works one time, then I am no longer able to reach that position. Do I have to somehow close the thread from before?

```
public void OnTimedEvent_scannerCyclic(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

  string sRawTxt = getRawData();

  // then separate/ remove the useless data
  string sComments = SeparateComments(sRawTxt);

}

[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{


    stdTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    stdTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimedEvent_scannerCyclic);
    stdTimer.Enabled = true;

    while (true)
  {
    // main program   
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);


  }
}
```

thanks a lot for help

So the only solution i figured was to use my own timer that i implemented in the main as below

```
TimeSpan deltaT = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
DateTime timeLastCall = DateTime.Now;

  while (true)
  {
    // main program   
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    if(currentTime - timeLastCall > deltaT)
    {
      Scanner.mainCyclicCall();
      timeLastCall = currentTime;
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
```

I dont have a lot of c# experience, it is actually my first little project. I dont know if there is a better way to cyclically access Clipboard in a console application. Also using a dispatcher timer did not work out, I read console apps dont have a dispather.

Comment: When you use a System.Timers.Timer then you inevitably have this problem again, it raises its Elapsed event on thread-pool thread.  This time you can't make it STA.  So don't use that timer.

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem as shown above for now, but i still dont like my solution. However, it needed to be running by yesterday even if its not finished yet it must be running now.